# Search results using the github API

Tags: github, github-api

I am using the following query:
https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=mysql&created:%3C2009-04-11&order=asc

and see the same results as:
https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=mysql&created:%3E=2013-04-11&order=asc

Looks the created is not taking into effect.
can you please help me if I am missing anything in the query?

Comment: I think there was a similar question here -https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45990626/github-api-call-filter-by-committer-date/45990853#45990853 . i.e. Try changing `&` to `+` and `=` to `:`.

Comment: If you have problems for my answer yet, feel free to tell me. I would like to study to solve your problems.

Comment: some how it is stil not working.

Comment: I tried  -curl https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=python+created:>2009-04-11&;page=1 -otest. but its giving a Error. when I try the same command on browser it works. I get the error-'page' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: @user826407 I'm sorry for the inconvenience. I updated my answer. Please confirm it.

Comment: @user826407 Did you try my updated answer? If my updated answer didn't work at your environment, feel free to tell me. I would like to think of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At [document of REST API v3](https://developer.github.com/v3/search/#parameters), parameters are added using `+`. So how about the following modification?

#### From :

```
https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=mysql&created:<2009-04-11&order=asc
https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=mysql&created:>=2013-04-11&order=asc
```

#### To :

```
https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=mysql+created:<2009-04-11&order=asc
https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=mysql+created:>=2013-04-11&order=asc
```

If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.

### Edit :

When you want to retrieve the data using curl, please use as follows. In this case, please enclose the URL using double quotations. The URL in this sample is from your comments.

```
curl "https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=python+created:%3E2009-04-11&page=1"
```

or

```
curl "https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=python+created:>2009-04-11&page=1"
```