# Search repos with GitHub API using date query

Tags: api, http, github, httprequest

If I make the following GET request to the GitHub API, I get about 58 entries:

```
https://api.github.com/search/repositories?&per_page=250&sort=updated&order=asc&q=%22github-octocat%22
```

However, the following with any date parameters return 0 entries:

**Created since date:** ( `created:>=2010-09-01` )

```
https://api.github.com/search/repositories?&per_page=250&sort=updated&order=asc&q=%22github-octocat+created:>=2010-09-01%22
```

**Date range:** ( `created:2012-08-13..2020-08-14` )

```
https://api.github.com/search/repositories?&per_page=250&sort=updated&order=asc&q=%22github-octocat+created:2012-08-13..2020-08-14%22
```

In the GitHub docs, under the section [Constructing a search query](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/rest/reference/search#constructing-a-search-query), the syntax is outlined as such:

`SEARCH_KEYWORD_1 SEARCH_KEYWORD_N QUALIFIER_1 QUALIFIER_N`

Thei GitHub docs at [Search by when a repository was created or last updated](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/searching-for-information-on-github/searching-for-repositories#search-by-when-a-repository-was-created-or-last-updated) outlines date formats like the two above, and [Query for values between a range](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/searching-for-information-on-github/understanding-the-search-syntax#query-for-values-between-a-range) outlines valid combinations of them. I suspect these examples are not meant for this use, as the examples use URLs intended for browsers, such as `https://github.com/search?q=case+pushed%3A%3E%3D2013-03-06+fork%3Aonly&type=Repositories`, instead of `api.github.com`, which is confusing too.

I'm trying to apply the patterns shown in the following resources in order to get a range of dates filter:

- [Github API call: filter by committer-date, answer by Poonacha](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45990853/1744084)
- [Get issues on a date range from Github enterprise API, answer by Al Neill](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50749472/1744084)

Any pointers greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you using a proper query parameter serializer? I'd expect more characters in your url to be urlencoded.

Comment: Hi @Evert—I am not sure what that would be in this case. Do you have any pointers? Thanks

Comment: Well, it depends on your language. So share your code, maybe someone can help.

Comment: @Evert, I am actually just doing a combination of GET requests using Postman as a testing service, and also replicating these in the browser, where I can't attach authentication tokens when entering a URL. I will be using a JS framework when I understand what the syntax is though.

Comment: Then look up how to urlencode variables in urls. Shouldn't be too hard to find!

Answer (score 1):

Even though the GitHub docs outlines the syntax as such:

```
SEARCH_KEYWORD_1 SEARCH_KEYWORD_N QUALIFIER_1 QUALIFIER_N
```

the parameters for date or similar, are not valid unless placed outside the `q` parameter. Instead of including `date` qualifier inside of the double quotes (shown as `%22` below):

```
q=%22mysearch+pushed%3A2017-09-01..2020-10-01+sort:updated%22
```

Pull them out, and add them after the closing quote of the `q` parameter:

```
q=%22mystring%22+pushed%3A2017-09-01..2020-10-01+sort:updated
```